# Javascript calculate() function not working in Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I've setup a form that performs certain basic calculations using Calculate() function in Javascript. It has 5 select boxes for QUANTITY, which when you change, the "litres" and "total amount" get updated.

The form works perfect in Chrome and Opera but DOES NOTHING! in Firefox and Safari.

You can check it here – http://jsfiddle.net/bksuru/ajsggpcg/

---

THE HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="60" colspan="5" valign="top"><h2>Variants:</h2></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40" align="left"><div class="variant">Flowers:</div></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Size<select name="flowers_size" id="flsz" type="text" size="1" class="select2" tabindex="1" ><option selected="selected">200 ML</option></select></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Price<input name="flowers_price" type="text" class="input5" id="flpr" tabindex="1" value="MRP 1495.00" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Quantity<select name="flowers_quantity" id="flqt" type="text" size="1" class="select3" tabindex="1" oninput="calculate()">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right"><label>Litres<input name="flowers_litres" type="text" class="input6" id="fllt" tabindex="1" value="0.000" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40" align="left"><div class="variant">Fruits:</div></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Size<select name="fruits_size" id="frsz" type="text" size="1" class="select2" tabindex="1" ><option selected="selected">200 ML</option></select></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Price<input name="fuits_price" id="frpr" type="text" class="input5" tabindex="1" value="MRP 1295.00" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Quantity<select name="fruits_quantity" id="frqt" type="text" class="select3" size="1" tabindex="1" oninput="calculate()">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right"><label>Litres<input name="fruit_litres" id="frlt" type="text" class="input6" tabindex="1" value="0.000" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40" align="left"><div class="variant">Plantations:</div></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Size<select name="flowers_size" id="flsz" type="text" size="1" class="select2" tabindex="1" ><option selected="selected">200 ML</option></select></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Price<input name="flowers_price" id="plpr" type="text" class="input5" tabindex="1" value="MRP 1195.00" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Quantity<select name="flowers_quantity" id="plqt" size="1" class="select3" tabindex="1" oninput="calculate()">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right"><label>Litres<input name="plantations_litres" id="pllt" type="text" class="input6" tabindex="1" value="0.000" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40" align="left"><div class="variant">Vegetables:</div></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Size<select name="vegetables_size" id="vesz" type="text" size="1" class="select2" tabindex="1" ><option selected="selected">200 ML</option></select></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Price<input name="vegetables_price" id="vepr" type="text" class="input5" tabindex="1" value="MRP 995.00" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Quantity<select name="vegetables_quantity" id="veqt" size="1" class="select3" tabindex="1" oninput="calculate()">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right"><label>Litres<input name="vegetables_quantity" type="text" class="input6" id="velt" tabindex="1" value="0.000" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40" align="left"><div class="variant">Cereals:</div></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Size<select name="cereals_size" id="cesz" type="text" size="1" class="select2" tabindex="1" ><option selected="selected">200 ML</option></select></label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Price<input name="cereals_price" id="cepr" type="text" class="input5" tabindex="1" value="MRP 895.00" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right" style="padding-right:14px;"><label>Quantity<select name="cereals_quantity" id="ceqt" size="1" class="select3" tabindex="1" oninput="calculate()">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </label></td>
    <td height="45" align="right"><label>Litres<input name="cereals_litres" id="celt" type="text" class="input6" tabindex="1" value="0.000" readonly="readonly" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="total">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"><label class="variant">Total Amount:<input name="total_amount" type="text" class="input7" id="tamt" tabindex="1" value="MRP 0.00" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
    <td align="right" valign="middle"><input name="Submit" type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

---

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
function calculate() {
        var flowersSize = 200;
        var flowersPrice = 1495;

        var fruitsSize = 200;
        var fruitsPrice = 1295; 

        var plantationsSize = 200;
        var plantationsPrice = 1195;    

        var vegetablesSize = 200;
        var vegetablesPrice = 995;  

        var cerealsSize = 200;
        var cerealsPrice = 895; 

        var flowersQuantity = flqt.options[flqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var fruitsQuantity = frqt.options[frqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var plantationsQuantity = plqt.options[plqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var vegetablesQuantity = veqt.options[veqt.selectedIndex].value;
        var cerealsQuantity = ceqt.options[ceqt.selectedIndex].value;

        var flowersLitres = flowersSize * flowersQuantity / 1000;
        var fruitsLitres = fruitsSize * fruitsQuantity / 1000;
        var plantationsLitres = plantationsSize * plantationsQuantity / 1000;
        var vegetablesLitres = vegetablesSize * vegetablesQuantity / 1000;
        var cerealsLitres = vegetablesSize * cerealsQuantity / 1000;

        flowersLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(flowersLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        fruitsLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(fruitsLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        plantationsLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(plantationsLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        vegetablesLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(vegetablesLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
        cerealsLitres = parseFloat(Math.round(cerealsLitres * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);

        fllt.value = flowersLitres;
        frlt.value = fruitsLitres;
        pllt.value = plantationsLitres;
        velt.value = vegetablesLitres;
        celt.value = cerealsLitres;

        var totalAmount = flowersQuantity * flowersPrice + fruitsQuantity * fruitsPrice + plantationsQuantity * plantationsPrice + vegetablesQuantity * vegetablesPrice + cerealsQuantity * cerealsPrice;

        totalAmount = parseFloat(Math.round(totalAmount * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

        tamt.value = "MRP"+" "+totalAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
```

---

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

BK Suru

Comment: any errors in your browser console

Comment: Don't think so Arun... Can you elaborate please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `onInput` event. 
This event is for `input` and `textarea` elements. **Not** `select` elements.
More specifically

```
<input type="password">
<input type="search">
<input type="text">
<textarea>
```

Use `onChange` event instead.

Apparently some browser do support `onInput` on other elements but that is not a standard.

**Edit (Added example):**

```
<select name="flowers_quantity" ... oninput="calculate()">
```

Change it to:

```
<select name="flowers_quantity" ... onchange="calculate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the method **oninput** to **onchange**

Comment: @BK Saru , Does it helpful to you ? Solved Now ?